# jQuery function makes responsive squares

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to edit this function

```
function adjustHeight() {
    var myWidth = $('.equ').width();
    var myString = myWidth + 'px';
    var myHeight = $('.equ').css('height', myString);
    return myHeight;
}

// calls adjustHeight on window load
$(window).load(function() {
    adjustHeight();
});

// calls adjustHeight anytime the browser window is resized
$(window).resize(function() {
    adjustHeight();
});
```

, to make it workable with multiple elements but...
I failed.
 [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mr8gj/857/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `each` statement:

```
$('.equ').each(
    adjustHeight(this);
);
```

This will call the function immediately.

Use anonymous function:

```
$('.equ').each(function() {
    adjustHeight(this);
});
```

```js
function adjustHeight(e) {
  var myWidth = $(e).width();
  var myString = myWidth + 'px';
  var myHeight = $(e).css('height', myString);
  return myHeight;
}

// calls adjustHeight on window load
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.equ').each(function() {
    adjustHeight(this);
  });
});

// calls adjustHeight anytime the browser window is resized
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('.equ').each(function() {
    adjustHeight(this);
  });
});
```

```css
#blue {
  width: 50%;
  /* Just for looks: */
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  margin: 25px;
}
#red {
  width: 45%;
  /* Just for looks: */
  background-color: red;
  margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="blue" class="equ"></div>
<div id="red" class="equ"></div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/mr8gj/858/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
       function adjustHeight(el) {
          $(el).height($(el).width());
        }

        // calls adjustHeight on window load
        $(window).load(function () {
            adjustHeight('.equ');
        });

        // calls adjustHeight anytime the browser window is resized
        $(window).resize(function () {
            adjustHeight('.equ');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use `each` is

```
$('.equ').each(function(){
    adjustHeight(this);
});
```